# How do you get flat file name and perform a row count from multiple flat files with different columns in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to get all the file names from a folder directory along with their row counts. (Also file size in bytes if possible) I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell. Here's what I've done so far:

I have created a *Foreach Loop Container*, set the Enumerator to *Foreach File Enumerator* and Expressions to a variable to the folder I want to loop over. I left the Files section with `*.*` and asked to retrieve `Name Only`. I have changed the Variable Mappings to a New Variable called `FullFilePath`, Container is `Package`, Value type is `String` and Value: is blank.

I then added a Data Flow to the Loop. Added a flat file source, row count, and OLE DB Destination. I changed the Flat file Source properties expression to the same Folder Variable in the Foreach Loop Container Expression. I added the Variable `RecordCount` to the Row Count function *(Int32, value 0)*. The OLE DB Destination creates a new table with the name OLE DB Destination.

The next step is a Execute SQL Task that does and `Insert Into DBO.FileData (FileName,RowCount) Values (?,?)`. I set 2 parameter mappings - 1) Variable Name from the Foreach Loop Container, FullFilePath and Data Type VarChar, 2) Variable from Row Count, RecordCount and Data Type Long.

I then have another *Execute SQL Task* that drops the table created by the data flow task. The problem is that with all the these step the Package still does not complete. It actually gets hung up and fails on the pre-execute. It says:

> Warning: Access is denied. Error: Cannot open the datafile 'FullFilePath' Error: Flat File Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.

Anything you see I could be doing wrong? Let me know if pictures would help.

Comment: First thing would be that you need to pass a full path and filename to the flat file source you can not just pass it a folder. Second you would need to have the filename generated by the foreach loop tacked onto the folder path that is currently set for the flat file source. this would be set thru an expression (connection string) on the flat file source. all of that aside you are going to need to change the metadata for each file that you are reading using that data flow and concept. you would be much better off doing that in a script task and returning an object variable

Comment: @SFrejofsky I figured it out. Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out finally. In order to loop over all of the files with varying headers and column counts I decided to change the option in the Flat File Source to unselect "File contains  headers." Doing this allowed the all the files to have the same #1 Column, which by default is Column 0(the first column in all of my files is some sort of a numeric field or ID). I was able to map this through row count and insert into a SQL table. Then I was able to finish the Foreach Loop and scribe the file name and row count into another SQL table to record the counts. It is however taking a really really really long time, i.e. it has been running for over 14 hours and it has only counted through 13 files. Granted some files are 250K+ rows but I wouldn't think it would take this long.

Comment: it should never take that long. the only reason that it should take that long is if your foreach loop is incorrect and you are iterating over the files way too many times. I have done millions of records over many many files it only taken an hour or so. Have you monitored the dataflow to see where the bulk of the time is being used up or checked the tables you are loading to make sure that the data is not duplicated?

Comment: @SFrejofsky I watched it go through the package process and saw it taking the longest time in writing the 'Column 0' into the OLE DB table. I checked the table it was writing into and it did not duplicate. It would write it from the flat file then truncate the table after the loop was complete. I changed the package to use a 'Raw File Destination' and it completed much more quickly, within 2 hours. Everything worked! I don't know why it was taking so long to write to SQL table, maybe because I'm running it to a remote server? Or maybe the server was busy?